# solrj very strange error with query result

Tags: solr, solrj, solr4

hello i have got strange error while using solr query result. 
now i am add simple txt file with one word 'anna', restart solr server and next try search that document. But i haven't got any result ? but if i add another document with content 'anna' and then restart solr. I have got only one result. So there is a bug in solr or i do not know something ?

I am using luke and everything is fine i have got two indexed document and when i try this query using luke everything is fine i have got 2 result. I am also check my for loop but its everything fine with that. So maybe some problem with solrj ?? I am using solr-core , and solrj ver 4.4.0. This is my code :

```
  QueryResponse qr;
        try {
            qr = fs.execute(solrServer);



            System.out.println("QYERY RESPONSE : " + qr);

            for (Entry<String, Object> r : qr.getResponse()) {
                System.out.println("RESPONSE: " + r.getKey() + " -> " + r.getValue());
            }
            SolrDocumentList dl = qr.getResults();
            System.out.println("--RESULT SIZE:[ " + dl.size() );


        } catch (SolrServerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

And it is very strange because this is my sysout:

> {**numFound=2**,start=1,docs=[SolrDocument{file_id=9882,
>   file_name=luk-search2.txt, file_create_user=-1, file_department=10,
>   file_mime_type=text/plain, file_extension=.txt,
>   file_parents_folder=[5021, 4781, 341, -20, -1],
>   *version*=1442647024934584320}]}

Num found is 2 but i have got only one result so ther is a bug in solrj library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In looking at the response, it shows a `start=1` value that is being passed in. The default value for start is 0, please see the [CommonQueryParameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#start) for reference. Since you only have two results for your query, and the start value is zero based, by specifying `start=1` you are asking for only the second document. Change this parameter to `start=0` and you will get both results back.